# How to deal with windows batch variable?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I have written the following batch but I'm afraid it doesn't work close to what I'm expecting:

```
@echo off

set filename=%1
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`forfiles /m "%filename%" /c "cmd /c echo @ftime"`) do (
set R1=%%F
)

:process
ping -n 60 127.0.0.1 > nul

for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`forfiles /m "%filename%" /c "cmd /c echo @ftime"`) do (
set R2=%%F
)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if !R1! == !R2! (
   echo no change
) else (
   echo kill process
   set R1=!R2!
   echo !R1!
   taskkill /im schedule2.exe
   schedule2.exe
)

endlocal

goto process
```

This batch is to check the modification time of a specified file (filename pass as parameter when calling this batch), the time was record first and after 60 seconds the modification time is checked again. if the file was modified, kill a particular process (which called schedule2.exe in my case) and then the time obtained at the very beginning was reset and change to the latest time observed. since using enabledelayedexpansion the value for R1 also gone as well, what can I do to achieve the result i want? many thanks

Comment: Move `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top of the script, directly under `@echo off`.

Comment: in this case value for filename also gone, but it is supposed to keep global and last forever

Comment: Follow @SomethingDark's advice **and** remove `endlocal`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `selocal/endlocal` bracket. There is nothing within that bracket that requires `delayedexpansion`.

You'd also need to change `!var!` to `%var%` throughout since `delayedexpansion` is then not invoked.

Your problem is that you are stiing `r1` within the subroutine, but since that is currently within a `setlocal/endlocal` bracket, the change is backed out when the `endlocal` is encountered.

Comment: He's setting `R1` and `R2` inside of `for` loops; won't he need delayed expansion to call them later?

Comment: @SomethingDark: er, no. Well, the display within the `if` statement should be of `r2` but that seems to be trying to display the changed value of `r1` which is being backed out by the `endlocal`. Removing the `setlocal` and `endlocal` (preferably moving the `setlocal` to directly after the `@echo off`) will set `r1` in the preamble and then loop repeating [potentially-change-`r2`. If changed, do your stuff and set `r1` to the new value.] No `delayedexpansion` required. Another mod might be to change the `if` to `if "%r1%"=="%r2%"` in case the time contains spaces (idk robocopy's format)